# Import functions from python classes located in python file into Robot Framework

Tags: python, robotframework

Consider I have this file hierarchy for my project:

- my_project (root folder)

  - `Resources`

    - `python_file.py` containing two classes: `FirstClass` and `SecondClass`
  - `Tests`

    - `test_suite.robot`

Here are the classes how they look like

```
    class FirstClass:
        def my_method:
            pass

    class SecondClass:
        variable = {
              key1: value1,
              key2: value
           }
```

Firstly, I want to use `my_method` in `.robot` file by importing whole class `FirstClass` using relative path.

Secondly, I want to use a dictionary from `SecondClass` by importing this class somehow (also using relative path).

Is this possible in RF?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason why you have `FirstClass` and `SecondClass` in one file? It feels like `FirstClass` provides test data and `SecondClass` provides cutoms keywords. If so, it doesn't make much sense to have it in one file. Also, why having `variable` inside a class? You can put it outside a class and inport it as a variable file into RF. Lastly, if you import `FirstClass` as a custom library (you can e.g. use decorators `@library` and `@keyword` for that), you can use `My Method` as a RF keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a class might not be directly accessible, its methods can be accessed using objects/instances within python. To do so, in your Setting you would have to add the python file -

```
*** Settings ***
Library    ../Resources/python_file.py
```

Now within your Test Cases you can invoke the function like any other keyword although it would be advisable to use the file name as well to prevent any confusion to the compiler as follows

```
*** Test Cases ***
${result}=    python_file.foo #Calls the new function foo that calls my_method
```

And within the python_file.py create another method -

```
def foo():
    obj = FirstClass()
    return obj.my_method()
```

Or

```
def bar():
    return SecondClass.variable
```

Comment: Actually, this is an elegant solution. I have never thought of adding another methods which can return object of the specific class or class variable itself. But that means the direct class import does not exist in RF?

Comment: It might exist, just that I am not aware of one.

Comment: As I figured out recently, it can be painful in case you have like 20 methods in a class and therefore you need to write another 20 methods just for returning the specific class methods.